# I can't seem to access the geolocation return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I'm trying to get the users location using the geolocation api, in my success callback I want to return the getPosition function with the position value.

I've tried a few approaches but non of them have been successful so far, this is where I'm at right now.

```
function getPosition() {

    // If geolocation is available, try to get the visitor's position

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
       console.log("Getting the position information...")
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }
    function successCallback(position) {
        return position
    }
    function errorCallback(error) {
        alert("Sorry, we can't retrieve your local weather without location permission.");
    }
};
const getLocalWeather = async () => {
    if(loading === 'loading') return
    setLoading('loading')
    console.log(getPosition())
    // this console log should return the position from getPosition
    setLoading('done')

};
```

The getPosition function itself works fine but I'm not able to access it's return value in the getLocalWeather function.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already familiar with async/await by the looks of things so wrap your `getPosition` code in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and then `await` the response in `getLocalWeather`.

This code may not work in the snippet, but I've tested it locally and it logs the position without any problems.

```js
function getPosition() {

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
 
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }

    function success(position) {
      res(position)
    }

    function error(error) {
      console.log("Sorry, we can\'t retrieve your local weather without location permission.");
    }

  });

};

async function getLocalWeather() {
  console.log(await getPosition())
};

getLocalWeather();
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.